# Getting QgsVectorLayer from QgsFeatureSink

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-processing, sink

I have created a feature sink like so:

```py
(sink, dest_id) = self.parameterAsSink(...)
```

And added a number of features to it. When I'm done processing, I want to post-process this layer using `gdal:rasterize`. But that requires me to pass a `QgsVectorLayer` (and its extent). How to get from that processed sink to a `QgsVectorLayer` + extent?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- Add [`QgsProcessingUtils`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Processing/QgsProcessingUtils.html#qgis.core.QgsProcessingUtils.mapLayerFromString) to imports.

  ```
   from qgis.core import QgsProcessingUtils
  ```
- After adding features, use `QgsProcessingUtils.mapLayerFromString` which returns `QgsVectorLayer` for a vector layer  as below.

  ```
   (sink, dest_id) = self.parameterAsSink(...)

   ...
   ...

   layer = QgsProcessingUtils.mapLayerFromString(dest_id, context)
  ```
- Now you can access the layer's properties.

  ```
   print(layer.extent())
  ```